# Opaque images when radio button selected, but need to hide the actual button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of attributes that are selected by radio buttons. Each attribute is identified by an image. The client wants the selected attribute to display normally, but the non selected attribute images to be opaque. I did this using some jQuery and applying a class depending on the radio button state.
The first segment forces anything except the pre selected options to be opaque on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input:not(:checked)').parent().addClass("nonactive");
    $('input:checked').parent().removeClass("nonactive");
});
```

And then this code handles the change on selection.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input').click(function () {
    $('input:not(:checked)').parent().addClass("nonactive");
    $('input:checked').parent().removeClass("nonactive");
});    
});
```

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/824kenok/

What he now wants is for the actual radio buttons to be hidden and have the image clickable. Both are simple enough to do on their own, but trying to maintain the opacity change on click breaks as soon as i make the image the clickable object and hide the actual radio buttons.

What suggestions do you have to combat this?

Comment: The image should be inside the label if it's supposed to trigger the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method does not require JavaScript. Put the radio buttons, with the images immediately after them, in the labels. Then you can use the `:checked` pseduo-class to update the images' opacity.
Clicking on the `label` acts as if you clicked on the radio itself, activating its `checked` property.

**Demo Using Radio Inputs**

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + img {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0.4);
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + img {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="attribImg">
    <label class="attribsRadioButton four" for="attrib-14-78">
        <input type="radio" name="id[14]" value="78" checked="checked" id="attrib-14-78" />
        <img src="http://www.metta.org.uk/travel/images/devon_ss.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<div class="attribImg">
    <label class="attribsRadioButton four" for="attrib-14-77">
        <input type="radio" name="id[14]" value="77" id="attrib-14-77" />
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-s_cOSZQwznU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEE/Y8jrlTapXMI/photo.jpg?sz=50" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<br />
<div class="attribImg">
    <label class="attribsRadioButton four" for="attrib-11-64">
        <input type="radio" name="id[11]" value="64" id="attrib-11-64" />
        <img src="http://www.metta.org.uk/travel/images/devon_ss.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<div class="attribImg">
    <label class="attribsRadioButton four" for="attrib-11-61">
        <input type="radio" name="id[11]" value="61" checked="checked" id="attrib-11-61" />
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-s_cOSZQwznU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEE/Y8jrlTapXMI/photo.jpg?sz=50" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

**Example of using radio input `name` attribute**

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: olivedrab;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Group 1</legend>
  <input type="radio" id="group1-radio1" name="group1" value="1" />
  <label for="group1-radio1">Radio 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="group1-radio2" name="group1" value="2" />
  <label for="group1-radio2">Radio 2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="group1-radio3" name="group1" value="3" />
  <label for="group1-radio3">Radio 3</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Group 2</legend>
  <input type="radio" id="group2-radio1" name="group2" value="1" />
  <label for="group2-radio1">Radio 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="group2-radio2" name="group2" value="2" />
  <label for="group2-radio2">Radio 2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="group2-radio3" name="group2" value="3" />
  <label for="group2-radio3">Radio 3</label>
</fieldset>
```

**Demo Using Checkbox Inputs**

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + img {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0.4);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + img {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="attribImg">
    <label class="attribsRadioButton four" for="attrib-14-78">
        <input type="checkbox" name="id[14]" value="78" checked="checked" id="attrib-14-78" />
        <img src="http://www.metta.org.uk/travel/images/devon_ss.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<div class="attribImg">
    <label class="attribsRadioButton four" for="attrib-14-77">
        <input type="checkbox" name="id[15]" value="77" id="attrib-14-77" />
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-s_cOSZQwznU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEE/Y8jrlTapXMI/photo.jpg?sz=50" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<br />
<div class="attribImg">
    <label class="attribsRadioButton four" for="attrib-11-64">
        <input type="checkbox" name="id[11]" value="64" id="attrib-11-64" />
        <img src="http://www.metta.org.uk/travel/images/devon_ss.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
<div class="attribImg">
    <label class="attribsRadioButton four" for="attrib-11-61">
        <input type="checkbox" name="id[12]" value="61" checked="checked" id="attrib-11-61" />
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-s_cOSZQwznU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEE/Y8jrlTapXMI/photo.jpg?sz=50" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what is required. The opacity is the wrong way round. The client wants the selected item to be normal, the non selected item to be opaque.

Comment: Both answers give the desired effect, however I went with the css only option.

Comment: Also requires `filter: alpha(opacity=1);` to work on all browsers

Comment: @DivineComedian Whilst your solution worked perfectly in the original situation, trying to duplicate it on another page it failed. I traced this to a difference in the "input" line of the attributes.
The original page used <input type="radio" name="id[14]" value="78" id="attrib-14-78" />, whereas the new page uses <input type="radio" name="id[1898][14]" value="78" id="attrib-14-78" />
A subtle difference, but for some reason name="id[1898][14]" instead of name="id[14]" breaks the function. What is the reason for this as I don't see the name being referred to in any way in your code.

Comment: @Popnoodles I tried using your solution from fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/824kenok/1 and that also fails if name="id[1898][14]" instead of name="id[14]"
I'm totally confused as to why this should be happening.

Comment: @StevePrice The `name` attribute on radio buttons ties them together.  So if 3 radio buttons have the same `name`, clicking on one will check it while unchecking the other ones.

Comment: @StevePrice I added an example

Comment: @DivineComedian I see what you are saying, but due to my radio buttons being for attribute selection, one group will have the following names.
name="id[1898][14],name="id[1898][11],name="id[1898][17].
This is a combination of product number and attribute option number. These cannot be reformatted without massive rewriting so I have to find a solution that works with this name convention.

Comment: @StevePrice Do you need to use radio buttons? If you have unique names for each input, then you can use checkboxes instead.  This way you can toggle the opacity for each image and still get the input value.  I added a demo at the end of my answer.